# react-native-open-map library not working

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

when latitude and longitude pass to these libraries react-native-open-map not navigating to maps Application and no error showing
OpenMap.show({
latitude: 40.778721,
longitude: -73.968188,
});

Answer (score 0):

#use this code

```
if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      Linking.openURL(`geo:0,0?q=${latitude},${longitude}(${this.state.treeClicked.info})`)
.catch(err => console.error('An error occurred', err));
    } else {
      Linking.openURL(`http://maps.apple.com/?ll=${latitude},${longitude}&q=${this.state.treeClicked.info}`)
.catch(err => console.error('An error occurred', err));
    }
```